# android button layout not appears

Tags: android, android-layout, button

hey I'm doing an android app, someone can tell me why is not showing button mi_perfil on my andriod screen? this is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     >

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foto"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" /> 

            <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                     />

                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:text="@string/Importar_Contactos"  />

            </LinearLayout>

   <Button android:id="@+id/miPerfil"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/boton_mi_perfil"
            android:onClick="MiPerfil"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip" />     

   </LinearLayout>
```

I want to put the button on the right of my screen, but it doesn't appears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout instead of the outer LinearLayout.

then you can arrange the image view to the left , and the button to the right.

Answer (score 0):

please try this your button code inside in child linearLayout

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/foto"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" /> 

        <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                 />

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:text="@string/Importar_Contactos"  />


<Button android:id="@+id/miPerfil"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/boton_mi_perfil"
        android:onClick="MiPerfil"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your XML according to your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foto"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" Importar_Contactos" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/miPerfil"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="dsfsd" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your button layout was with width and height match parent, that's why your button was hiding behind. I have used another child linearlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foto"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt3"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt4"
            android:text="Importar_Contactos" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/miPerfil"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:onClick="MiPerfil"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your orientation to **"vertical"**.
Than it works fine.